# Progress Bar for Action Queries

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm running a bunch of action queries (make table queries) that are linked to multiple backend tables.  I wanted to show a progress bar since these queries total about 12 minutes to run.  When I run the code, I see an hour glass but I'm not able to see the progress bar.  I tried the code below but it's not displaying a progress bar.  Is there another way I can show progress with action queries?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub PS_Report_Date_AfterUpdate()

Dim intCnt As Integer
intCnt = 0

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

DoCmd.Close acReport, "Report Name", acSavePrompt

' Display information that action queries are about to run
MsgBox "Running Action Queries, Standby...", vbInformation

' Turn on hourglass
DoCmd.Hourglass True

' Turn on status meter
SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "working...", 100

' Start DoCmd for action queries
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Make_Table_Query1"
intCnt = intCnt + 10
SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Make_Table_Query2"
intCnt = intCnt + 10
SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Make_Table_Query3"
intCnt = intCnt + 10
SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Make_Table_Query4"
intCnt = intCnt + 10
SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Make_Table_Query5"
intCnt = intCnt + 10
SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Make_Table_Query6"
intCnt = intCnt + 10
SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Make_Table_Query7"
intCnt = intCnt + 10
SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Make_Table_Query8"
intCnt = intCnt + 10
SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt  

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Make_Table_Query9"
intCnt = intCnt + 10
SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Make_Table_Query10"
intCnt = intCnt + 10
SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt  

' Set warnings back on
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

' Remove the progress bar
SysCmd acSysCmdRemoveMeter

' Remove the status bar
DoCmd.Hourglass False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add DoEvents. I make a loop for not repeating same commands.

```
Private Sub PS_Report_Date_AfterUpdate()

Dim intCnt As Integer
Dim qname As String
intCnt = 0

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

DoCmd.Close acReport, "Report Name", acSavePrompt

' Display information that action queries are about to run
MsgBox "Running Action Queries, Standby...", vbInformation

' Turn on hourglass
DoCmd.Hourglass True

' Turn on status meter
SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "working...", 100

For I = 1 To 10
  qname = "Make_Table_Query" & CStr(I)
  ' Start DoCmd for action queries    
  DoCmd.OpenQuery qname
  intCnt = intCnt + 10
  SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt
  DoEvents
Next I

' Set warnings back on
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

' Remove the progress bar
SysCmd acSysCmdRemoveMeter

' Remove the status bar
DoCmd.Hourglass False

End Sub
```

If it will not work, add

```
Dim qdf AS QueryDef
```

to the up of the sub, and change loop

```
For I = 1 To 10
  qname = "Make_Table_Query" & CStr(I)
  Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(qname) 
  ' execute the query    
  qdf.Execute
  intCnt = intCnt + 10
  SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, intCnt
  DoEvents
Next I
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It looks like my problem was in my db settings.  Doh!  Tried the different methods you mentioned and these work too.